# changeing time coordinate value in xarray data set

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netcdf data set imported in xarray:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('PATH')
```

My data set looks similar to this:

```
Dimensions:    (latitude: 500, longitude: 600, time: 120)
Coordinates:
latitude (latitude) float32 -35.22 -35.17 -35.12 ... -10.38 -10.33 -10.28
longitude (longitude) float32 10.27 10.32 10.38 10.43 ... 40.12 40.18 40.22
time (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-01-01 2022-01-02 ... 2022-04-30
```

When I want to check the time values with the following code:

```
ds.time.values
```

Then I get this:

```
array(['1990-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1990-01-01T03:00:00.000000000',
   '1990-01-01T06:00:00.000000000', '1990-01-01T09:00:00.000000000',
   '1990-01-01T12:00:00.000000000', '1990-01-01T15:00:00.000000000',
   '1990-01-01T18:00:00.000000000', '1990-01-01T21:00:00.000000000'],
  dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

But I now want to change the time values such that they now only look like this, when I use the previous code:

```
array(['2010-01-01T00:30:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

How can I change my code such that I only have this one time coordinate?

Comment: isn't your desired result simply the array time?

Comment: the thing is, I just want to have one single array time, at the moment I have these 8 entries, but I only want to have one time value/coordinate

Comment: Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.